# Get Shipping Rates/Carriers from an existing Order

Tags: shipping

Is it possible to retrieve all shipping carrier/rates starting from an Order instead of using a quote ?

**UPDATE**

With the following code I'm converting the order to a quote and the address.
There is still some issue:
`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::requestShippingRates()` is returning false (this is called by `collectTotals()`)

```
$converter = mage::getModel('sales/convert_order');
$quote = $converter->toQuote($this->getOrder());
$quoteAddress = $converter->toQuoteShippingAddress($this->getOrder());

foreach ($this->getOrder()->getAllItems() as $item) {
//            $itemW = $item->getWeight();
//            $itemQty = $item->getWeight();
//            $itemTotalWeight = $itemW * $itemQty;

                $quoteItem = $converter->itemToQuoteItem($item);
                $quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
                $quoteItem->setQty($item->getQtyOrdered());
                $quoteItem->setWeight($item->getWeight());
                $quote->addItem($quoteItem);

                $quoteAddress->addItem($quoteItem);
            }
$quoteAddress->setQuote($quote);
$quoteAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quoteAddress->collectTotals();
```

Comment: ever find out what was going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I read your question wrong. I think this is not possible, but you should get the quote from the order via `$order->getQuoteId()`

**OLD**

what about:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/shipment_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', $order->getId());
```

and then just sum the costs up.